# Including assets from Twig views using AsseticBundle

Tags: assets, symfony

In Symfony 1.4 I use to include just the needed assets with:

**apps/myApp/config/view.yml** (general assets to be used in every page)

```
stylesheets:   [main.css]
javascripts:    [lib/jquery.js, lib/jquery.qtip.js, backend/main.js]
```

**apps/myApp/modules/someModule/templates/someTemplateSuccess.php** (assets just for this view, partial, etc)

```
<?php use_stylesheet('backend/datagrid.css') ?>
<?php use_javascript('backend/datagrid.js') ?>
```

and then finally linking those in **apps/myApp/templates/layout.php**:

```
<?php include_stylesheets() ?>
<?php include_javascripts() ?>
```

So, how to do this using the AsseticBundle in Twig views?

I'm really confused... thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I got here:

https://github.com/kriswallsmith/symfony-sandbox/commit/f1fc1d0cf2fe69660f94f33719a4508d6e9e25ae

and it **WORKS!**

it goes like this:

**src/MySite/MyBundle/Resources/css/datagrid.css**

to include it in the view:

**src/MySite/MyBundle/Resources/views/MyViews/myview.html.twig**

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {% stylesheets '@MySiteMyBundleBundle/Resources/css/datagrid.css' %}
        <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

and finally, lets print it:

**app/Resources/views/base.html.twig**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}Lol!{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Great!

**UPDATE:**

I still don't know why but:

```
{% stylesheets '@MySiteMyBundleBundle/Resources/css/*.css' output='css/all.css' %}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

Only works setting debug to false, so the best way to do this is configuring it:

**app/config/config.yml**

```
# Assetic Configuration
assetic:
    debug:          false
    use_controller: true
    write_to: %kernel.root_dir%/../web
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
```